# loaddata command deserializes fixture with a future model state

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations, django-fixtures

So... Here is the issue I ran into:

My Django project was broken : I landed on the default homepage saying `start project` and `manage.py runserver [::]:8000` said `run migrate`.

**All** my migrations were applied (the database was in the right state) so I did not understand what was going on. (So if someone has any clue about this *reset*, I'll be glad to read his/her answer)

---

Anyway, I ran `manage.py reset_db` and `manage.py syncdb` and here comes the *real* issue:

The initial migrations succeed without any problem but then, I have some fixtures that are loaded via data migrations and this loading fails with

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: Problem installing fixture 'scopes_fixtures.json': Could not load utils.MPTTScope(pk=0118cd35-e6dd-4a38-8cc8-f9cf07cfdd05): (1054, "Unknown column 'enabled' in 'field list'")`
.

#### Fixture is deserialized using a *future* app models definition

I understand that the `loaddata` command deserializes the fixture using the **latest** app models definition but this is a bit annoying since the `enabled` field is only added in a later migration.

Is there any option that would force `loaddata` to deserialize the fixture using the app models definition established by the previous migrations?

Comment: Is it an option just to roll back to a previous migration?

Comment: My project setup was completely broken, the django migration system believed that there was no app or database setup. So it was not possible to rollback to the previous migrations and not possible to run a manage.py migrate command since the fields already existed in MySQL.

Comment: Have you considered creating a data migration? Or is that an option? Auto loading data has been deprecated since 1.7 according to docs. The app state will be ensured. The intial_data.json always gets out of sync when fields are added/edited/removed and going in and constantly updating the json can be pretty annoying.

Comment: @Victor Do you mean creating a migration with obj = MyObject.create(name='test') and running it? I agree, there will be no problem with a JSON deserialization but how can I do that easily if I have several hundreds of records? Do you have a link to the fixture loading depreciation? loaddata seems still a valid option in Django 1.8.

Comment: @NicolasW. see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-data-with-fixtures.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly the answer you were looking for but let me give you a perspective that might help solve this problem. Use data migrations so the state of the app is always the same when this data is being imported.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#data-migrations

```
$ ./manage.py makemigrations [appname] --empty
```

### 0012_some_migration.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models

def import_data(apps, schema_editor):
    ModelName = apps.get_model("yourappname", "ModelName")
    ModelName.objects.bulk_create([...]) 

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('yourappname', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(import_data),
    ]
```

Comment: Thank you Victor. This is, indeed, not the answer I was looking for but it will help me fix most of the issues I had with loaddata. :-) BTW, do you know why Django uses the latest model definition to load data that was created with a previous model state?

Comment: I would assume that it would use the definition when you import the model because the concept of different model states doesn't really make sense until django migrations came into the framework but that is a guess.